# Unable to use Snackbar after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-snackbar, snackbar, android-studio-2.3

I have recently updated my Android Studio version to 2.3

I am working on a project now and I've noticed that I am unable to import Snackbar class. I never had that problem before.

I can use it by adding compile `'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'` and I can import it then, but I don't think I should have to do that instead of just using Android's `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;`

This is are my dependencies from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have also tried to play around with DataBinding concept in my project but I don't think this could cause that issue?

Thank you.

Comment: SnackBar is available in `com.android.support:design` library

Comment: could you please tell me what version of `com.android.support:design` do I need to import to make sure I am using the newest one?

Comment: the latest one is  `'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'`

Comment: @Alim Parkar thank you very much. sorry if my question was very trivial but I spent last hour trying to figure out what's wrong.. should not Android Studio add that automatically to a new project btw? it doesn''t seem to do it with any of my new projects

Comment: Studio does not add the library automatically as it does not know which library the class could belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'` in your dependencies. As the library is not added you are unable to get the Snackbar class.